# Como contar elementos con una caracteristica especifica en un array- JS

Tags: array, condiciones, bucles, iteradores, javascript-metodo

Debo contar los items que empiecen con la letra "b", habia intentado con un loop for para iterar sobre el array, pero no se como aplicar la condicion la letra del inicio.

["foo","bar","baz","qux","echo"]
*

- contar el total de items que inicien con el caracter "b"
- output =>  2
  */
  let arr = ["foo","bar","baz","qux","echo"];

*let result = [];

let newArr = arr.slice(1,3);

result.push(newArr.length)

console.log(result)

Comment: ¿Cómo lo necesitas? ¿Con `for`?  ¿Con `reduce`? ¿Con `filter`? Hay demasiadas formas de hacerlo, pero creo que una de las más simples es `let result = arr.filter(e => e[0] === "b").length`

Comment: Holaa, me gustaria hacerlo con for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El ejercicio es simple. Basicamente recorres cada palabra del arreglo, preguntando si empieza con "b". Si la palabra empieza con "b", incrementas el contador, si no, pasas a la siguiente palabra. Finalmente imprimes el conteo.

Utilizando `for` quedaría:

```js
let arr = ["foo","bar","baz","qux","echo"];
let result = 0

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i][0] === "b"){
        result++;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Utilizando `for of`:

```js
let arr = ["foo","bar","baz","qux","echo"];
let result = 0

for (let palabra of arr) {
    if(palabra[0] === "b"){
        result++;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Utilizando `filter`:

```js
let arr = ["foo","bar","baz","qux","echo"];
let result = arr.filter(e => e[0] === "b").length
console.log(result);
```

Usando `reduce`:

```js
let arr = ["foo","bar","baz","qux","echo"];
let result = arr.reduce((a,e) => e[0] === "b" ? a + 1 : a , 0)
console.log(result);
```

Usando `forEach`:

```js
let arr = ["foo","bar","baz","qux","echo"];
let result = 0

arr.forEach(palabra =>{
    if(palabra[0] === "b"){
        result++;
    }
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Genial!, gracias. Estoy empzando con js y tenia muchas dudas para plantear mi condicion :)